# Why does onCompletionListener fire immediately with attached AudioEffect?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

When I add code to attach a `BassBoost` effect, the `onCompletionListener` of my `MediaPlayer` is fired immediately. Here's the relevant code:

```
player.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(song.filename));

// everything is fine if I comment out these 3 lines
BassBoost boost = new BassBoost(0, player.getAudioSessionId());
boost.setStrength((short) 1000);
player.attachAuxEffect(boost.getId());

player.prepare();
player.start();
```

I have experimented with the order of this particular code to no avail. Finally, I logged the `getCurrentPosition()` and `getDuration()` values in the completion handler and wouldn't you know it: they're both zero!

My current thought is that attaching the effect requires asynchronous preparation, but I haven't been able to find any further clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out from another question being answered. If you specify the audio session in the effect constructor *and then* call `attachAuxEffect`, it will fail. This works:

```
BassBoost boost = new BassBoost(0, player.getAudioSessionId());
boost.setStrength((short) 1000);
// ALREADY ATTACHED IN CONSTRUCTOR ... player.attachAuxEffect(boost.getId());
```